# How to set the connectionManagement maxconnection programmatically?

Tags: connection, app-config

How do I set the maxconnection value programmatically?

This is the entry in my app.config.

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "100" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Also, how do I set throttle programmatically?

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
     <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" 
    maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to set the same. For the first one, the below seem to fit the bill? Does that work for you?

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
```

and the below on the httpwebrequest object

```
webrequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 200;
```

The link below shows and example of throttling programming

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-wcf-services/9780596157210/ch04s08.html